# How can I exclude COUNT results which are 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that gets a count of all the tickets assigned to a team:

```
SELECT 'Application Developers' AS team, COUNT(Assignee) AS tickets
from mytable WHERE status = 'Open' AND Assignee like '%Application__bDevelopers%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Desktop Support' AS team, COUNT(Assignee) AS tickets
from mytable WHERE status = 'Open' AND Assignee like '%Desktop__bSupport%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Network Management' AS team, COUNT(Assignee) AS tickets
FROM mytable WHERE status = 'Open' AND Assignee LIKE '%Network__bManagement%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Security' AS team, COUNT(Assignee) AS tickets
from mytable WHERE status = 'Open' AND Assignee = '%Security%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Telecom' AS team, COUNT(Assignee) AS tickets
from mytable WHERE status = 'Open' AND Assignee = '%Telecom%'
```

The result is:

```
        team              tickets
Application Developers       6
Desktop Support             374
Network Management           0
Security                     7
Telecom                      0
```

How can I exclude the results that come back with "0" tickets?

Comment: I believe that `COUNT` that you aliased into `tickets` is accessible from the WHERE clause... so use `AND tickets != 0`

Comment: @sjagr: For SQL that would be `<>`, not `!=` :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks! Too used to MySQL. I'll post the correction as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` for each query:

```
SELECT 'Application Developers' AS team, COUNT(Assignee) AS tickets
from mytable WHERE
    status = 'Open'
    AND Assignee like '%Application__bDevelopers%'
HAVING COUNT(Assignee) <> 0
```

I'd suggest @NoDisplayName's answer because your query as it stands is quite inefficient.

Comment: @NoDisplayName Thanks, I had a suspecting feeling.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Union all between bunch of queries Change your query like this.

Use `Having clause` to filter the group's where `count <> 0`

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Application__bDevelopers%' THEN 'Application Developers'
         WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Desktop__bSupport%' THEN 'Desktop Support'
         WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Network__bManagement%' THEN 'Network Management'
         WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Security%' THEN 'Security'
         WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Telecom%' THEN 'Telecom'
       END             AS team,
       Count(Assignee) AS tickets
FROM   mytable
WHERE  status = 'Open'
       AND ( Assignee LIKE '%Application__bDevelopers%'
              OR Assignee LIKE '%Desktop__bSupport%'
              OR Assignee LIKE '%Network__bManagement%'
              OR Assignee = '%Security%'
              OR Assignee = '%Telecom%' )
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Application__bDevelopers%' THEN 'Application Developers'
            WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Desktop__bSupport%' THEN 'Desktop Support'
            WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Network__bManagement%' THEN 'Network Management'
            WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Security%' THEN 'Security'
            WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Telecom%' THEN 'Telecom'
          END
HAVING Count(Assignee) <> 0
```

Comment: This will return different results than what op is expecting if Assignee column has values like `'Application__bDevelopers_teamA'` , `Application__bDevelopers_teamB`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of writing this query would be to avoid all of these UNION ALL queries and do something like

```
SELECT Teams 
      ,Tickets 
FROM 
(
SELECT NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Application__bDevelopers%' 
                     THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),0) AS [Application__bDevelopers]
      ,NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Desktop__bSupport%' 
                     THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),0) AS [Desktop__bSupport]
      ,NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Network__bManagement%' 
                     THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),0) AS [Network__bManagement]
      ,NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Security%' 
                     THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),0) AS [Security]
      ,NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN Assignee LIKE '%Telecom%' 
                     THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),0) AS [Telecom]
FROM mytable
WHERE [status] = 'Open' ) Q
 UNPIVOT (Tickets FOR Teams IN ([Application__bDevelopers], [Desktop__bSupport]
                               ,[Network__bManagement],[Security],[Telecom]))up
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Common table expressions instead of using `Having`

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT 'Application Developers' AS team, COUNT(Assignee) AS tickets
from mytable WHERE status = 'Open' AND Assignee like '%Application__bDevelopers%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Desktop Support' AS team, COUNT(Assignee) AS tickets
from mytable WHERE status = 'Open' AND Assignee like '%Desktop__bSupport%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Network Management' AS team, COUNT(Assignee) AS tickets
FROM mytable WHERE status = 'Open' AND Assignee LIKE '%Network__bManagement%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Security' AS team, COUNT(Assignee) AS tickets
from mytable WHERE status = 'Open' AND Assignee = '%Security%'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Telecom' AS team, COUNT(Assignee) AS tickets
from mytable WHERE status = 'Open' AND Assignee = '%Telecom%'

)
SELECT 
*
FROM CTE
WHERE tickets>0
```