# How can I rewrite this query in a more efficient way?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 'Application Developers' as team, COUNT(assignees) as tickets from TABLE20 where status <> 'Closed' AND assignees like '%Application Developers%' HAVING COUNT(assignees) <> 0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Desktop Support' AS team, COUNT(assignees) AS tickets FROM TABLE20 WHERE status <> 'Closed' AND assignees LIKE '%Desktop Support%' HAVING COUNT(assignees) <> 0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Enterprise Help Desk' AS team, COUNT(assignees) AS tickets FROM TABLE20 WHERE status <> 'Closed' AND assignees LIKE '%Enterprise Help Desk%' HAVING COUNT(assignees) <> 0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Network Management' AS team, COUNT(assignees) AS tickets FROM TABLE20 WHERE status <> 'Closed' AND assignees LIKE '%Network Management%' HAVING COUNT(assignees) <> 0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Query Writers' AS team, COUNT(assignees) AS tickets FROM TABLE20 WHERE status <> 'Closed' AND assignees LIKE '%Query Writers%' HAVING COUNT(assignees) <> 0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Security' AS team, COUNT(assignees) AS tickets FROM TABLE20 WHERE status <> 'Closed' AND assignees LIKE '%Security%' HAVING COUNT(assignees) <> 0  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Server Admins' AS team, COUNT(assignees) AS tickets FROM TABLE20 WHERE status <> 'Closed' AND assignees LIKE '%Server Admins%' HAVING COUNT(assignees) <> 0  UNION ALL

ORDER BY tickets DESC
```

This query produces the following result:

```
team            tickets
Desktop Support 424
Enterprise Help Desk    96
Server Admins       46
Query Writers       15
Network Management  13
Application Developers  6
Security        6
```

How can I rewrite this query so it is doesn't look like a total newb wrote it? =)

Comment: What database is this for?  Why can't you use a group by?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about review of working code. It should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Off-topic, yes, but this should not go on Code Review without [substantial improvement](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql).

Comment: I didn't think it was a terrible question, they figured out something that works and asked for help improving it.  Downvoting all answers just because you don't like the question seems silly.

Comment: @GoatCO OP did not "figure out something that works" but rather adopted the quickest (read: laziest) fix from [their previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27749320/2359271) without bothering to understand and implement the superior approaches unanimously recommended there. And now, instead of asking those users about the approaches they recommended, asks another question.

Comment: @AirThomas Fair enough, didn't dig in to their history.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a database that supports `cte` you can use:

```
;WITH cte AS(SELECT CASE WHEN assignees like '%Application Developers%' THEN 'Application Developers' 
                        WHEN assignees LIKE '%Desktop Support%' THEN  'Desktop Support'
                        ....
                   END AS team
            FROM TABLE20 
            WHERE [status] <> 'Closed'
            )
SELECT team,COUNT(*) CT 
FROM  cte
GROUP BY team
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

If not:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN assignees like '%Application Developers%' THEN 'Application Developers' 
            WHEN assignees LIKE '%Desktop Support%' THEN  'Desktop Support'
            ....
       END AS team
       ,COUNT(*) CT
FROM TABLE20 
WHERE [status] <> 'Closed'
GROUP BY CASE WHEN assignees like '%Application Developers%' THEN 'Application Developers' 
            WHEN assignees LIKE '%Desktop Support%' THEN  'Desktop Support'
            ....
         END
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

`GROUP BY` is a basic element of `SQL` that allows for exactly the functionality you're after. Instead of counting groups of elements independently and combining the results, you can count all elements from multiple groups in one fell swoop.

Comment: Please explain the downvote.

Comment: some people just enjoy down voting when they cant understand

Comment: Thanks Goat CO.  The cte works great!  I'm still learning SQL and trying to understand the various commands and how they work together.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
SELECT assignees, count(*) as tickets
FROM TABLE20
WHERE status <> 'Closed'
GROUP BY assignees
ORDER BY tickets DESC
```

Comment: And I say the same, please comment downvote!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume that `assignees` isn't the exact string listed, and that's why they're using `LIKE`.

Comment: Agree with Goat CO here as it looks like you can have 'Desktop Support, Application Developers' in assignees.

Comment: I downvoted this one, for the reason given above, plus two more: 1) code-only answers are crap; 2) if you don't know what the OP is trying to do, ask them to clarify in a comment, not by taking wild guesses in an answer.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion jarlh, but this does not work because the values in the assignees column are not consistent, hence the "LIKE"  command.

Comment: @AirThomas, thanks for explaining your downvote.